# hidding symbols from a static library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries, symbols, visibility

I have a c++ shared library - `libA.so`. I hide symbols using `-fvisibility=hidden` flag. The symbols which should be visible have the following attribute: `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))`. That library links to the static library - `libB.a`. All symbols from that static library (`libB.a`) should be visible only for the shared library (`libA.so`). I have compiled the static library also with the flag `-fvisibility=hidden`. I get desired results -  symbols from `libB.a` are only visible for `libA.so` but are hidden for the outside world, for example the following command `nm -C libA.so` doesn't show symbols from `libB.a`.

Could you explain how the flag `-fvisibility=hidden` works internally with the static library in the above scenario ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visibility feature has been added to support limiting interfaces of shared libraries i.e. reducing number of exported functions. By default (without `-fvisibility=hidden`) linker will export *all* functions in library which is,  in most cases, not what you want.

Visibility is ignored during static library link i.e. when linking `libB.a` and pulling functions from it linker will not look at visibility annotations at all. On the other hand, after functions are pulled (from `libB.a`) into final shared library (`libA.so`) they will be exported and pollute libA's interface unless you've hidden them via `-fvisibility=hidden` when compiling the static library itself.